# Codeception Module \Helper\Api could not be found and loaded

Tags: php, module, helper, codeception, modulenotfounderror

When i try to add some Helper in Api.suite.yml and run build:
`php vendor/bin/codecept build`
, then get error:

```
Building Actor classes for suites: Api

In ModuleContainer.php line 102:

Module \Helper\Api could not be found and loaded

build
```

My Helper autogenerated with that command:
`php vendor/bin/codecept generate:helper Api`

directory location in attachment [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Hjl.png)

code in Api.suite.yml:

```
actor: ApiTester
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - REST:
        depends: Laravel
        part: Json
    - \Helper\Api
  config:
    - Laravel:
        environment_file: .env.test
step_decorators:
  - \Codeception\Step\AsJson
```

code in Api.php:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\Support\Helper;

// here you can define custom actions
// all public methods declared in helper class will be available in $I

class Api extends \Codeception\Module
{

}
```

Codeception version: Codeception 5.0.7

i tried to put other location in Api.suite.yml:

```
\project\tests\Support\Helper\Api
\tests\Support\Helper\Api
\Support\Helper\Api
\Helper\Api
\Api
```

it still doesn't work for me

Comment: The module name specified in `Api.suite.yaml` should match the FQCN, so `\Tests\Support\Helper\Api` in your case (with the capital T for tests). If that doesn't work then it's most likely an autoloading issue.

Comment: It helped me, ty @Liiva . Problem was solved. It's was so obviously, sorry fot that.